# DotNet Core console app: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest

Tags: c#, .net-core

Im just trying to run a DotNet Core console app on a Windows Server 2012 R2 but I keep getting this error:

*Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Application.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.Web.Administration', version: '11.1.0'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.5/Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll'*

The dll that is missing is inside the /publish folder...
I used Dotnet publish with the correct Runtime Identifier (win81-x64)

I installed the Dotnet runtime 2.0.7 on the server

Comment: which output did you copy to the target server?

Comment: So I ran `dotnet publish -c Release -r win81-x64` and copied all output in `\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win81-x64` to the server

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Always use the publish output when deploying to a target sever.

It can be found in

```
bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win81-x64\publish
```

in your case (self-contained application)

or in

```
bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish
```

for framework-dependent deployments.

The output in the directories above are meant to be used in development only, since they are specific to machine and user configuration built with.

Comment: Just had a similar problem.  Specifically:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (StatProcessing.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions', version: '1.1.2'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'

I resolved it by setting up a publish operation on my development system to produce a Win10x-64 build.  Once I did that and then deployed to my server, it started to work.  Thanks @martin.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I deployed the wrong publish folder.

I decided to take the time a setup a `publish profile`.
In solution Explorer...`Right Click` on the Project -> Publish
or from the menu Build->Publish

[.NET Core application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

Using a publish profile you can set the target location to something simple

```
drive:\Publish\[project]
```

This will save you from haveing to navigate 10 levels deep an possibly copying the wrong folder.

[Deploy .NET Core apps with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156)