# Failed to launch app error An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest

Tags: c#

I have an app writing in .NET5

I use MSI installer to deploy the app on other machines.

Locally, the app works well.

But while installing on another machine, clicking on the executable doesn't work.
The app isn't launching.

In the event viewer I see this:

```
.NET Runtime error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest  (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
```

I'm using VS 22.

.NET 5 Runtime installed on the machine.

**Is there an issue with using ClickOnce with .NET 5?**

Comment: Is .net 5 runtime or sdk installed on that machine?

Comment: Hi, yes, sure, updated the question to include this info

Comment: Does this help ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896443/an-assembly-specified-in-the-application-dependencies-manifest-was-not-fou

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia Gutierrez - I added this property to my csproj, but it didnt help :( also i'm not publishing the proj

Comment: what is the content of MyApp.deps.json include it in the question please

Comment: Also check this in case it helps - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3215