# dotnet add package xunit.runner.visualstudio did not work

Tags: c#, xunit

I get this error:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (testhost.deps.json) was not found: package: 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities', version: '17.8.0-release-23523-03' path: 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.dll'

I tried this solution:

```
dotnet add package xunit.runner.visualstudio
```

when I run `dotnet test`, I still get the same error.

Did you have to do something else to resolve?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897649/11309214